# kannel bluetooth configuration require

Tags: kannel

I have installed kannel and it is working , i am not sure how to configure kannel.conf  so that sms is sent from browser to blue tooth nokia phone.

http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=+91XXXXXXXX&text=hello%20from%20kannel

```
i get   3: Queued for later delivery in browser
```

kannel.conf contains

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/tmp/smsaccess.log"


group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar


#Nokia Modem

# SMSC GSM
group = smsc
smsc = at
smsc-id = nokia_smsc
modemtype = nokiaphone
device = /dev/rfcomm0
speed = 9600
pin = BlueZ


group = modems
id = nokiaphone
name = "Nokia Phone"
detect-string = "Nokia Mobile Phone"
init-string = "AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0"
speed = 115200
enable-hwhs = "AT+IFC=2,2"
need-sleep = false
no-pin = true
no-smsc = false
sendline-sleep = 100
keepalive-cmd = "AT+CBC;+CSQ"
broken = true
message-storage = "ME"
enable-mms = true
```

any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Its a modem issue ... this message means that kannel received the sms correctly but don't know where to send it and/or the route is not available.

Check logs and/or for error and paste it here ... may be we can help you further .

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

You better to use a USB modem for this instead of Bluetooth. All the other settings are correct. I am using Kannel without having problem.